# Linear search not continuing to end of array

Tags: python-3.x

The program is meant to show the position (using counter) of all numbers which are 71. It only finds the first one before stopping.

```
numbers = [23,76,45,71,98,23,65,37,93,71,37,21]
search_value = 71
counter = 0
found = False

while found == False and not counter == len(numbers):
    if numbers[counter] == search_value:
        found = True
    else:
        counter = counter + 1
if found == True:
   print("Found at position ",counter)
else:
   print("No match found")
```

Version of python is 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Your program stops after finding the first occurrence of 71 because at that point the value of `found` will change to `True` which will in turn cause one side of the `and` operator to be `False`(`found == False`) hence the whole condition will be `False` because 'and' operators requires both sides to be `True` for it to evaluate to `True`.

You can accomplish what you want to do by:

```
numbers = [23,76,45,71,98,23,65,37,93,71,37,21]
search_value = 71
counter = 0
found = False


while counter < len(numbers): #if counter is equal to/more than the length we'll be outside the list range
    if numbers[counter] == search_value:
        print("Found at position ",counter)
        found = True
        counter += 1 #Same as counter = counter + 1
    else:
        counter += 1
if not found: #Same as asking whether found is False
   print("No match found")
```

Comment: Just as a hint: You can replace `if found != True:` with `if not found:`.
I find it much more readable.

Comment: @JakobSachs So much more readable infact, my bad didn't replace that

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your `while` loop only runs while `found = False`.

If I understand your question correctly you want to find each index (`counter`) for each occurrence of `search_value`.

To achieve this you could use a `for` loop to iterate over the list. So the resulting code would be:

```
numbers = [23,76,45,71,98,23,65,37,93,71,37,21]
search_value = 71
found = False

for counter in range(len(numbers)):
    if numbers[counter] == search_value:
        found = True 
        print("Found at position ",counter)

if not found:
   print("No match found")
```

You could also alter the code above if you don't want a separate message for each time the value got found.

That could look like this:

```
numbers = [23,76,45,71,98,23,65,37,93,71,37,21]
search_value = 71
found_indexes = []

for counter in range(len(numbers)):
    if numbers[counter] == search_value:
        found_indexes.append(counter)

if len(found_indexes) == 0:
   print("No match found")
else:
   print("Found at positions: ", found_indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using this thanks all for responses

```
numbers = [23,76,45,71,98,23,65,37,93,71,37,21]
search_value = 71
found = False

while found == False:
     for counter in range(0,len(numbers)):
        if numbers[counter] == search_value:
            print("Found at position ",counter + 1)
            found = True


found = False
```